# Wait until element is active/enabled to perform action(like click/select) on Siteprism Capybara?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

In Siteprism i need to find out to wait for an element to be enabled before performing any action like click/select.

currently i am using this by Siteprism:

@page.wait_for_page_element(10)

But looks like that's not enough waiting. Still my script fails as the element was visible but not enabled. Need a solution.

Comment: Can you share your code? for better understanding @Subash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you've defined the element - but I assume you just did something like  `element :page_element, '#my_page_element'`  -  The problem with this is it doesn't give any indication that the element is a actually a field and doesn't allow for using any of the field matching filters.  If instead you define the element as

```
element :page_element, :field, '#my_page_element'
```

Then I believe calling wait_for_page_element on it will actually wait for it to be enabled since Capybara finds only enabled fields by default.  If it doesn't or if you want to wait for a disabled field to be on the page then you can pass filter options (disabled, checked, readonly, etc) to wait_for_page_element

```
@page.wait_for_page_element(10, disabled: false)
```

Comment: I have actually used:  @page_wait_until_element_visible   . This helped me.

Comment: ok -- although visible is not the same as enabled - unless you specify the :field selector for the element - in which case it does default to only enabled fields